# Node gallery colorbox / lightbox etc language problem

Tags: javascript, media

[Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) doesn't work with Drupal [Node Gallery](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_gallery) module when the site language is set to anything other than English.
When the language is switched to English [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) starts working immediately.
I have used this module before (on other sites) with no problems at all.
I tried to switch between [colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) and [cssbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/cssbox), exact same behaviour.

I have this problem on two websites. One is a clean install. The other has a lot of modules enabled.

Any idea how to get this working?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You'll have to post more details about the site; is there anything in DB logs? Anything in browser console? Can you replicate the issue on a clean install?